# Connect to Ubuntu server instance in AWS asks for password when it shouldn't

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, ssh, putty

I have an instance of an Ubuntu Server, I'm trying to connect via PuTTY but it keeps asking my password, so I think this means my keypair I generated is not working?

I tried this solutions and all of them result in the same thing, asking for password (of course, I did not type any password when generating my private key)

1.- In hostname I put my IP address

2.- In hostname I put DNS public name

3.-In hostname I put ubuntu@DnsPublicName

4.-In Connection -> Data I tried with and without ubuntu in the auto-login username
5-In connection -> SSH ->  Auth I have use either a private ppk key and public. None worked

6.- Tried KiTTY instead of PuTTY and the result is the same

7.- The strangest of all: I tries to connect to a co-worker's instance that it is working well and he connects all the time to it, and the same case: Prompt asks for password

8.- I created an elastic IP and assoiciated to the instance and connected to it.

9.- I generated again my private key but using a key passphrase, I put something like "12345" and then when I connected I types this password, and it says access denied

10.- I tried to use the ssh command in windows with the -v argument to debug whats going on: ssh -v -i default_keypair.pem ubuntu@myHost, this is the output:

```
OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.6p1, LibreSSL 2.6.4
debug1: Connecting to 52.9.100.77 [52.9.100.77] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file default_keypair.pem type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file default_keypair.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.6
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version xxxxxxx
debug1: no match: xxxxxxx
debug1: Authenticating to 52.9.100.77:22 as 'ubuntu'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64@openssh.com compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64@openssh.com compression: none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(2048<3072<8192) sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:HyUi5jL0iOh06FZFW8cnvyKKdnu0eKqx1aiRWmCbQMw
debug1: Host '52.9.100.77' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\Praxis/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory
ubuntu@52.9.100.77's password:
```

For what I see it seems I need some files, but I have no idea how to get them. Another detail is that no matter what password I put (empty, root, admin) I always get the Access Denied error

Also, a few data about my PC and my server:
-My PC: Windows 10 x64
-My server: Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS (HVM)

So, do you think you could guide me a bit?
Thanks!

Comment: I do not think that you are missing files. Do you have your sshd daemon configured server side?

Comment: What is extension of private key you are trying? I think putty doesn't like default .pem and you need to use PuttyGen to convert to .ppk.

Comment: And I guess you are following this documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/putty.html

Comment: Yes, it is ppk, created via PuttyGen. I tried both using a passphrase and without it.

Comment: That is the documentation I'm following indeed. Not sure about the sshd daemon, Andrea, since I'm using a server in AWS

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

Your EC2 instance is NOT configured to use a key pair. The first method offered by the SSH server is `password`. Note: You are not using putty in your example, you are using the SSH command line tool. Also, you cannot regenerate your private key without uploading and installing the public key to the instance. That is why you received an access denied error.

Go to the AWS EC2 Console. Select your instance. In the bottom window pane look for `Key pair name`. If this is empty, this confirms that no key pair is assigned. If there is a key pair name there, then I am wrong about password authentication. Double check that you are using the correct key pair and you are actually connecting to the correct IP address assigned to the EC2 instance.

You can use AWS Session Manager to connect to instances that have broken SSH configurations. Tip: The first item is to update the SSM agent as this feature is not present in the SSM agent in the current AMIs.

[New – AWS Systems Manager Session Manager for Shell Access to EC2 Instances](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-session-manager/)

Comment: Double checked: The keypair is there, below my instance. The ip is correct and I am using the correct key file :(

Comment: Double check the path to the key pair file. Your SSH trace contains the error message: `key_load_public: No such file or directory`